# Count How many Data in a month based on Criteria

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables, `master_kategori_project` which is contain category of projects and `project` which is contains how many project in a specific month in a specific year. below is my `master_kategori_project` table.

```
id| category_project | description |
1 | Category 1       | descrip 1   |
2 | Category 2       | descrip 2   |
3 | Category 3       | descrip 3   |
```

and my `project` table look something like this

```
id| id_category_project | name_project | start_date |
1 | 1                   | Project 1    | 27-01-2017 |
2 | 2                   | Project 2    | 29-02-2017 |
```

i want to make a table that contain chart like this, u can see from the table on **january** i have 3 projects of kategori 1, 5 projects of kategori 2, 7 projects of kategori 3 and so on

how can i write an query that have something like this? the chart is automatically build by the table itself.

[image]

this is my model and i believe i did it wrong, because i can't put the data into the correct month

```
public function get_kategori_totals($mnth, $year=null)
{   
    $yr=date('Y');
    $select = "
        SELECT COUNT(category_project),start_date,category_project
        FROM
            project
        LEFT JOIN
            master_kategori_project
        ON
            project.id_category_project=master_kategori_project.id
        WHERE 
            MONTH(start_date)='$mnth'".
            (($year == null)?" AND YEAR(start_date)='$yr' GROUP BY category_project":"AND YEAR(stat_date)='$year' GROUP BY category_project");
    return $this->db->query($select);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query.

```
  SELECT id_category_project, month(start_date), count(distinct name_project) as project_count
  FROM project
  WHERE start_date IS NOT NULL AND start_date <> '0000-00-00'
  GROUP BY 1,2
  ORDER BY 2,1
```

Comment: this code is not dynamic isn't it? like if i add another category project, then i need to change the code also

Comment: I updated it. It will fine for more categories also but you will get individual row for each category.

Comment: so i need to put this for each month? is that what u saying?

Comment: ok i think i can tweak it somehow, thank for now ill just give +1, ill accept ur answer when i have try this